# Do I need to start a String with a null value if I reserve it's space as a .space in MIPS32 assembly?

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I'm trying to reserve space to store a string in it using a .space:

```
.data
  myString: .space 16
```

I've got an example code from my teacher that says that I must start that string with a null value (0), I don't understand why though, why is this needed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Needed for what?  `.space` already fills with zeros, in case you care about reading bytes from the static initialized value instead of bytes you later store.

Comment: @PeterCordes What my teacher is saying is that the first character in the string needs to be a null value (0), however I don't really see the logic in that.

Comment: Yeah, there is no logic in that unless you have code that wants to read it before storing a string, so it reads as the empty string.  But like I said, you already *are* satisfying that requirement with `.space`.  `.byte 0` ; `.space 15` would end up with the same 16 bytes of zeros in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter what's in the buffer if your code definitely writes the buffer before it ever reads it.  Otherwise it does matter that it starts with 0, so it's the empty string if read as an implicit-length 0-terminated string.

But you already *are* doing that: **`.space` fills with zeros**.  The following would end up with exactly the same 16 bytes of zeros in memory:

```
myString:
  .byte 0
  .space 15
```

If you want to make it extra explicit in the source that there's a 0 at the start, this is worth considering.  (e.g. if you pass this address to something that reads it before the first write). Even then, if you know what `.space` does, it's still just clutter.  A comment on the `.space` would be sufficient.

I'm not sure where you'd find documentation for classic MIPS assemblers like MARS that `.space` fills with zero, but that's explicitly the case for a Unix assembler like GNU `as` that's mostly compatible with classic MIPS assemblers: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Space.html